# encrypting a project, data, etc

Tags: security, encryption

I carry my laptop with my projects and db's, some of them may contain some sensitive data, i to know how to encrypt some folders, i've just downloaded androsa file protector, but it's too slow, with over 60.000 files and several GB's of data it takes forever, someone know something faster??

Comment: This question belongs on SuperUser, not StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/), it's cross-platform, fast enough, industry-proven standards, etc.  [Plausible deniability](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=plausible-deniability) is a good feature of it too.

Comment: Yes, until you try to cross the border with it (http://yro.slashdot.org/article.pl?sid=08/02/07/1412229) :-)

Comment: That's precisely the point of plausible deniability.  They ask you for a password, you tell them the "fake" one that just has a couple boring text files or whatever on it.

Comment: Indeed. And after you tell them the fake one they seize your laptop. Plausible deniability only works in theory, sadly. Mind you, I use TrueCrypt myself and I up-voted your answer - I'm just pointing out that it's not a solution to all life's problems.